# Stop hibernate from throwing sensitive data when an exception is thrown

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, log4j2

I am new to hibernate and Im using JPA +Hibernate + Spring Boot for my applications. The logging is being handled using log4j2 . When my application is correctly throwing an exception (in my case DataIntegrityViolationException or EntityExistsException) Hibernate is logging the exception with stackTrace. Which is great as it helps debug. However it also logs application sensitive data which I do not want to be present in the logs.  Is there a setting in the properties file that can be set or modified to prevent this from happening. I don’t want to create an appender for hibernate in my log4j2.xml and mask specific words in the final log.

Comment: Can you give an example, with fake content, of exactly what Hibernate is logging and the parts that you consider to be sensitive?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson 
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:[com.xyz.package#EmployeeId[customer=ralph,cc={110001014478100104},address={Harry Potter st},ssn={75648684},phone={1234567}]]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:[com.xyz.package#EmployeeId[customer=ralph,cc={110001014478100104},address={HarryPotter st},ssn={75648684},phone={1234567}]]. I dont want those details logged

Answer (score 0):

You can add global exception in spring boot and you can log the exception message only follow this tutorial - https://www.studytonight.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-global-exception-handling

Or you can do some try catch for each call and  throw  exception with your customized message as below.

```
Try {
  //call
} catch (Exception ex){
   throws CustomizedRunTimeException(“yourMessage”)

}
```

The class look like below

```
public class CustomizedRunTimeException extends RunTimeException { 
    public CustomizedRunTimeException(String errorMessage) {
        super(errorMessage);
    }
}
```